# Plotting vertical lines across 2 subplots with the same time axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot

I am new to programming and I've been trying for days with different functions to plot two vertical lines across 2 subplots that share the time x-axis but have a completely different y-axis, but either the lines just don't appear on the plot or the entire plot becomes empty. 
The lines should represent the beginning and end of a thunderstorm so they should be located at specific times, in this case 16:00 and 20:30. I have to repeat this for 3 other thunderstorms, and I can't even get one right. 
The code I have is this:

```
ce28 = pd.read_csv('Data Source 1-06282017.efm', header=None, 
parse_dates=True)
col=ce28[1]
cuentas = 120
promedios = [sum(col[i:i+cuentas])//cuentas for i in range(0,len(col),cuentas)]

proms=promedios[924:]
print(len(proms))

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

inicio = datetime(2017,6,28,14,0,0)
fin = datetime(2017,6,28,23,0,0)

seconds = (fin - inicio).total_seconds()
delta = timedelta(minutes=1)

tiempo = []
for i in range(0, int(seconds), int(delta.total_seconds())):
tiempo.append(inicio + timedelta(seconds=i))

print(len(tiempo))

datos= pd.read_csv('28-6-2017_28-6-2017_min.txt', sep='\t', header=None, 
parse_dates=True)
col1=datos[2]
col11=col1[900:]
print(len(col11))

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(25,8))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1) 

ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
graf0 = ax0.plot(tiempo, proms,color='b')
plt.ylabel('Intensidad de E (kV/m)',fontweight='bold')
plt.grid(True)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[1], sharex = ax0)
graf1 = ax1.plot(tiempo, col11, color='b')
plt.xlabel('Tiempo Local',fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Cuentas por minuto',fontweight='bold')
plt.grid(True)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0,15,30,45],interval=1))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M')) 
plt.ylim(1300,1450)
plt.setp(ax0.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.0)
plt.margins(x=0)
plt.show()
```

And that gives this beautiful graph: 
[image: beauty]

What I want to achieve is something like this, I drew the lines with power point and obviously the quality isn't the same:
[image: desired]

Any help you can give me will be truly appreciated! Thank you.

Data: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cjolnsns37r8sby/AAAiijE3DWR1yR0G1qys7g47a?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me:

```
ax0.axvline(pd.to_datetime('2017-06-28-00:00:00'), color='k', linestyle='-.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do it

```
f = plt.figure()
ax1 = f.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = f.add_subplot(212)

rect = patches.Rectangle((10,2),3,1,linewidth=1,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')

f.patches.extend([patches.Polygon([(0.4,0.1),(0.4,1.5)],
                                  fill=True, color='g', alpha=0.5, zorder=1000,
                                  transform=ax2.transData,
                                  figure=f)])
```

Note that the coordinates of the line (polyon) refer to data space of ax2.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't run this, it says 'invalid syntax' ):

Comment: I guess this is due to copy and paste on your side. The code is ok.

Answer (score 0):

The main changes involve `red_ordinates`. I also added limits to the y-axis in the upper plot. The tick labels for the x-axis are a mess. I hope that's because I made up the data and didn't take the time to work them out properly. My main object was to suggest a way of getting the vertical lines.

The main idea is that since `tiempo` is in date-time units, to plot the vertical lines, their x-coordinates must also be in date-time units; hence, the way `red_ordinates` is calculated and used.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import matplotlib.dates as md
import numpy as np
import random

tiempo = np.arange(771).astype('<i8').view('M8[m]').tolist()
proms = [random.gauss(0,1) for _ in range(len(tiempo))]
col11 = [1380+5*random.gauss(0,1) for _ in range(len(tiempo))]

red_ordinates = np.linspace(10,50,2).astype('<i8').view('M8[m]').tolist()

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(25,8))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1) 

ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
graf0 = ax0.plot(tiempo, proms,color='b')

ax0.plot([red_ordinates[0], red_ordinates[0]], [-3.5, 3.5], color='r')
ax0.plot([red_ordinates[1], red_ordinates[1]], [-3.5, 3.5], color='r')

plt.ylim(-3.5, 3.5)
plt.ylabel('Intensidad de E (kV/m)',fontweight='bold')
plt.grid(True)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[1], sharex = ax0)
graf1 = ax1.plot(tiempo, col11, color='b')

ax1.plot([red_ordinates[0], red_ordinates[0]], [1300, 1450], color='r')
ax1.plot([red_ordinates[1], red_ordinates[1]], [1300, 1450], color='r')

plt.xlabel('Tiempo Local',fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Cuentas por minuto',fontweight='bold')
plt.grid(True)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0,15,30,45],interval=1))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M')) 
plt.ylim(1300,1450)
plt.setp(ax0.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.0)
plt.margins(x=0)
plt.show()
```

Resulting plot:

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this and it shows an error concerning the ticks, it says that the number of ticks exceeds the maximum allowed and I don´t understand why, but I'm going to keep trying.

Comment: Would it be possible to post your data somewhere and to include your complete code, as it stands now, in your question?

Comment: Yes, let me try to do so! Thanks